# Unhandled ClassNotFound Exception when reading object

Tags: java, exception, objectinputstream, classnotfound

So, I'm trying to read in an Object from a file, and I can't figure out why I'm getting this exception, or how to fix it. Maybe you guys can help me out? I've tried messing around with the way I read the object, but can't get it quite right. Here is my code I'm getting the error on the line that reads listOfEmployeesIn[i] = (Employee) objIn.readObject();:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class ProjectFive{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Random rn = new Random();
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("employees.txt", "rw");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("employees.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("employees.txt");
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        Object x;

        long SSN;
        float salary;
        int age;
        float maxSalary = 200000;
        float minSalary = 20000;
        long SSNRange = 1000000000;

        String[] names = {"Matty Villa"};
        Employee[] listOfEmployeesOut = new Employee[20];
        Employee[] listOfEmployeesIn = new Employee[20];

        for(int i=0;i<listOfEmployeesOut.length;i++){
            SSN = (long)(rn.nextDouble()*SSNRange);
            salary = rn.nextFloat()*(maxSalary - minSalary)+minSalary;
            age = rn.nextInt(57)+18;
            listOfEmployeesOut[i] = new Employee(SSN, names[i], salary, age);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<listOfEmployeesOut.length;i++){
            objOut.writeObject(listOfEmployeesOut[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<listOfEmployeesIn.length;i++){
            listOfEmployeesIn[i] = (Employee) objIn.readObject();
        }
        file.close();
        fileOut.close();
        objOut.close();
        fileIn.close();
        objIn.close();


    }
}   
class Employee implements Serializable{
    public long socialSecurityNumber;
    public String fullName;
    public float salary;
    public int age;

    public Employee(long socialSecurityNumber, String fullName, float salary, int age){
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
        if(fullName.length() != 50){
            fullName = resizeString(fullName);
        }
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String resizeString(String s){
        if(s.length() < 50){
            for(int i = s.length(); i<=50; i++){
                s += ' ';
            }
        }else{
            s = s.substring(0,50);
        }
        return s;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String out = "Name: " + fullName + "\nSalary: " + salary + "\nSocial: " + socialSecurityNumber
            + "\nAge: " + age;
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post the stack trace. What this usually indicates is that you don't have a library available with a class definition for some object that's in the stream you're trying to read.

Comment: are you complaining about a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per JAVA API for [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29), the method `readObject` throws checked exceptions - `IOException, ClassNotFoundException`

So either throw this exception from `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

or handle it using `try/catch` blocks:

```
        try {
            listOfEmployeesIn[i] = (Employee) objIn.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Well that was incredibly easy. Thanks. Haha

Comment: @ScaryWombat, its a checked exception and needs to be handled in the code. So it should fix the issue posted by OP, am I missing something here?

Comment: wow, I have re-read the OP question and I can still not figure out that he is complaining about code not compiling.

Comment: yes that is a compilation error and fixing it runs the program without issues.

Comment: @user2065083 Yes... Because now your program is ignoring the issue and moving on even though the error is still occuring.